# Testing after complete brake job, no pressure while applying brakes

Tags: brakes, nissan, altima

Context: Replaced the front disc brakes and back drums for a Nissan Altima 2001

Problem: The brakes don't have any pressure while applied, or in other words the pedal sinks to the floor. Their seem to be a lot of troubleshooting options, the most useful seem to be ensuring movement in the calipers, and ensuring a tight fit for all of the brake fluid connections. A similar post seems to suggest there might be additional tools [required](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27164/i-have-replaced-my-brake-cylinders-but-the-brake-pedal-goes-to-the-floor).

Any advice or suggestions will help. Thank you.

Comment: Is your brake fluid container full? Did you bleed the brake lines?

Comment: The container is full. Let me get more familiar with [bleeding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD8tXRWWCrg).

Comment: On my car, if everything is mechanically working, that would likely be a brake bleeding issue. There should be fluid coming out of each bleeder valve with no air. Once that's done, a few pumps of the brakes should bring it back to normal.

Comment: Were the calipers or rear wheel cylinders replaced?

Comment: yes, purchased complete kits for both the front and back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will want to use a vacuum pump to remove any remaining air in your system**

[**Using a hand vacuum pump**](https://www.google.com/search?q=hand%20vacuum%20pump&oq=hand%20vacuum%20pump&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3359j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=brake%20vacuum%20pump), you can get a low end one, will remove the frustration of bleeding brakes with two people.  One to pump the brake one to open the bleeding nipple on the calipers and master cylinder.

If your pedal is going to the floor after servicing your hydraulic brake system you more than likely have air in your system.  The tool referenced above should allow you suck a high volume of brake fluid through your system to evacuate any remaining air in the system.

**[Anti-lock brakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-lock_braking_system)**

Various manufacturers of brake systems, such as Siemans, will have procedures specific to the component to remove air.  Air can get trapped in a series of valves that are necessary to bleed off hydraulic pressure to prevent locking.  Some will call for you to turn the key all the way on and bleed the brakes with the power enables at the ignition.  I have encountered a system that required the car actually be turned on and then off again.

I have researched your vehicle for an anti-lock bleeding procedure and have been unable to find anything special about your system that requires anything OoB.

Here is some additional info on using a hand vacuum pump to evacuate air from your system.

- **https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24195/9164**

Comment: Thank you, will give the vacuum pump [procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTY2iBkFeV0) a shot. Just out of curiosity what does OoB stand for?

Comment: Sorry.  OoB is an IT term.  It means Out of Band.  Something that is done that isn't normal would be my inferred meaning.  Good luck with your brakes!

Comment: btw, if you like an answer on the site, please upvote it.   :-)